# "Server Error in '/' Application" When uploading an image

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, photo-upload

I want to upload a profile picture to my system.But I click upload, **"Server Error in '/' Application"** message appears. Also I have figured out the URL is little bit different than Correct URL should be like this.
**/ProfileController/UploadPhoto**
But the URL in the here is **/admin/ProfileController/UploadPhoto**
What should do in order to make this work?
This is my code in controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadPhoto(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
     if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
     {
            var user = Session["userID"].ToString();
            var fileExt = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
            var fileName = user + ".png";

            if (fileExt.ToLower().EndsWith(".png") || fileExt.ToLower().EndsWith(".jpg"))
            {
                 var filePath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/images/profile/") + fileName;
                var directory = new DirectoryInfo(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/images/profile/"));

                if (directory.Exists == false)
                {
                     directory.Create();
                }
                ViewBag.FilePath = filePath.ToString();
                file.SaveAs(filePath);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", new { Message = ManageMessageId.PhotoUploadSuccess });

            }
            else
            {
                  return RedirectToAction("Index", new { Message = ManageMessageId.FileExtensionError });

            }
     }
     return RedirectToAction("Index", new { Message = ManageMessageId.Error }); 
}
```

This is the code in view

```
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dd>
            @if (User != null)
            {
                 var imgUrl = Url.Content("Content/Images/" + User + ".png") + "?time=" + DateTime.Now.ToString();
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <img src="@imgUrl" height="250" width="250" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="mngimg">
                        @using (Html.BeginForm("UploadPhoto", "ProfileController", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                        {
                            <div class="input-field col s12">
                                <input type="file" name="file" id="files" onchange="this.form.submit()" />
                            </div>
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </dd>
    </dl>
```

[image: Image of the error I get]

**RouteConfig.cs**

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "AdminPanel",
            "admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new {`controller="Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new[] { "OnlineElection.Controllers.Admin" } );
```

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name:"Default",
            url:"{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults:new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces:new[] { "OnlineElection.Controllers" }
        );
```

Comment: Have you decorated your Controller class with a `RouteArea` attribute to create the "/admin/" part of the URL?

Comment: @Colinm, No I haven't done anything like that. That's why I cant figure out how it is happening

Comment: Please update your question to include the exact error message as "Server error in '/' application" could mean anything.

Comment: Give me a minute Colin. I will add a screenshot

Comment: @Colinm, I have already inserted the complete code.

Comment: How are you mapping your routes?

Comment: To be honest I did this only looking at a code. Still I don't have a proper knowledge about this. And this is the whole code I have. Please correct the code if you see any error. And about the routes as usual way I haven't done it by giving controller and all

Comment: Do I have to code for "onchange="this.form.submit()"" ?

Comment: Your `using Html.BeginForm` route parameters are wrong, `ProfileController` should just be `Profile`. Please familiarize yourself with MVC Routing and update the question with the relevant routing information from the `Routes.cs` file in the App_Code folder (assuming you're not on  ASP.NET Core) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx

Comment: @ Colinm, You are correct. When I change ProfileController into Profile it worked. But still it doesn't display the image if there are any prevoius images uploaoded as I expected. If you can please give me a hand with that too. Also I will add RouteConfig.cs to the question. Most important thing is I must thank you for your effort, help and answers. Thank you once again.

Comment: In the view write "Profile" instead of "ProfileController"

Comment: Did the file upload work? Your other question is related to a new issue and hence a new question. If what I said did the trick for the above error then I will post it as an answer

Comment: Yes it worked Thanks for asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form URL you're posting to is invalid.

When using Controllers, you omit the `Controller` word and use only the name of the controller, in this case `ProfileController` becomes just `Profile`, this also counts for URL's.

Your `Html.BeginForm` should in fact be
`@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadPhoto", "Profile", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))`

Comment: If you don't mind may I ask a little little help? Actually you are the best person for this. I get another exception in the same problem. If you can please take a look. It worked properly but started creating exceptions later. If you can do it is big help for me. please check the link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41120975/how-to-fix-microsoft-csharp-runtimebinder-runtimebinderexception-cannot-perform