# How to fix Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I get the following exception in my system.This system worked properly. But suddenly got and exception.  I tried doing debugging. But I couldn't find the anything. This is about a profile picture upload. I did some removing of code and I got the error. But then I again add those codes but nothing happen. I tried some solutions in the internet but didn't work. I'm new to this work so please help me if you can. I tried removing some of the codes then I got an error saying invalid operation.
How can I fix this?
I tried to debug and find where the problem occurs, unfortunately I couldn't find where it is.But I guess the problem should be in these codes. These two codes created the exception

Code part 1

```
                    @{
                        var imgUrl = @Url.Content("~/Content/profile/" + Model.SID + ".png") + "?time=" + DateTime.Now.ToString();
                    }
                    <img id="user_img" src="@imgUrl" height="50" width="50" style="margin-top:2px" />
                </li>
```

Code part 2

```
@if (Model.SID != null)
                            {
                                var imgUrl = @Url.Content("Content/profile/" + Model.SID + ".png") + "?time=" + DateTime.Now.ToString();
                                <div class="input-field col s12">
                                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                                        <img id="user_img" src="@imgUrl" height="1" width="1" />
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="mngimg">
                                        @using (Html.BeginForm("UploadPhoto", "Profile", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                                        {
                                            <div class="input-field col s12">
                                                <input type="file" name="file" id="files" onchange="this.form.submit()" />
                                            </div>
                                        }
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            }
```

```js
@section Scripts
{
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

            $.validator.setDefaults({
                errorClass: 'invalid',
                validClass: "valid",
                errorPlacement: function (error, element)                 {
                    $(element)
                        .closest("form")
                        .find("label[for='" + element.attr("id") + "']")
                        .attr('data-error', error.text());
                },
                submitHandler: function () {

                    event.preventDefault();
                    var SID = $("[name='SID']").val();
                    var fName = $("[name='fname']").val();
                    var lName = $("[name='lname']").val();
                    var dob = $("[name='dob']").val();
                    var email = $("[name='email']").val();
                    var pw = $("[name='password']").val();
                    var confirmPw = $("[name='confirmPassword']").val();
                    var phone = $("[name='phone']").val();
                    var address = $("[name='address']").val();

                    var user = {

                        SID: SID,
                        FirstName: fName,
                        LastName: lName,
                        DOB: dob,
                        email: email,
                        Password: password,
                        Phone: phone,
                        Address: address

                    }

                    //console.log(SID + " " + email + " " + password);

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'saveChanges',
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        data: JSON.stringify(user),
                        dataType: 'Json',
                        async: true,
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data == true) {
                                Materialize.toast('Details Updated Successfully !!!', 4000, 'blue')
                            }
                        }

                    });

                }

            });

            $.validator.addMethod("regx", function (value, element, regexpr) {
                return regexpr.test(value);
            }, "must contain more than 8 characters & at least 1 Alphabet and 1 Number");

            $("#form").validate({
                rules: {
                    SID: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 10,
                        maxlength: 10
                    },
                    fName: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 4,
                        maxlength: 20
                    },
                    lName: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 4,
                        maxlength: 20
                    },
                    dob: {
                        required: true,

                    },
                    email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    },

                    Phone: {
                        required: true,
                        regx: /^\d{10}$/,
                        minlength: 10,
                        maxlength: 10
                    },

                },

                messages: {
                    fName: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: "Should be minimum 4 characters",
                        maxlength: "Should be maximum 20 characters",

                    },
                    lName: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: "Should be minimum 4 characters",
                        maxlength: "Should be maximum 20 characters"
                    },
                    Phone: {
                        minlength: "Enter valid phone number",
                        maxlength: "Enter valid phone number"
                    }

                }
            });

        });


    </script>
}
```

```html
<form id="form" style="width:100%; height:auto; margin-left:1%; margin-top:1%" method="post">

 @*<div class="input-field col s12 ">
   <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
   <input id="img" name="img" type="image" value="" readonly="readonly" style="margin-top:5%; margin-bottom:1%">
   <label for="img">Profile Picture</label>
  </div>*@
 <div class="input-field col s12 ">
  <i class="material-icons prefix">subtitles</i>
  <input id="SID" name="SID" type="text" value="@Model.SID" readonly="readonly">
  <label for="SID">Student ID</label>
 </div>
 <div class="input-field col s12">
  <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
  <input id="fname" name="fname" type="text" class="validate" value="@Model.FirstName">
  <label for="fname">First Name</label>
 </div>
 <div class="input-field col s12">
  <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
  <input id="lname" name="lname" type="text" class="validate" value="@Model.LastName">
  <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
 </div>
 <div class="input-field col s12">
  <i class="material-icons prefix">Address</i>
  <input id="address" name="address" type="text" class="validate" value="@Model.Address">
  <label for="lname">Address</label>
 </div>
 <div class="input-field col s12">
  <i class="material-icons prefix">phone</i>
  <input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" class="validate" value="@Model.Phone">
  <label for="lname">Phone</label>
 </div>
 <label for="dob" style="margin-left:10%">Date of Birth</label>
 <div class="input-field col s12">
  <i class="material-icons prefix">D</i>
  <input id="dob" name="dob" type="date" class="validate" value="@Model.DOB.Value.ToString("dd/ MM/ yyyy")">  @*@Model.DOB.Value.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy")*@

 </div>
 <div class="input-field col s12">
  <i class="material-icons prefix">email</i>
  <input id="email" name="email" type="email" class="validate" value="@Model.email">
  <label for="email">Email</label>
 </div>
 <div class="input-field col s12">
  <i class="material-icons prefix">lock_outline</i>
  <input id="password" name="password" type="password" class="validate">
  <label for="password">Password</label>

 </div>
 <div class="input-field col s12">
  <i class="material-icons prefix">lock_outline</i>
  <input id="confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" type="password" class="validate" onkeyup="check()">
  <label for="confirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
  <lable name="checkpassword"></lable>
 </div>
 <div class="input-field col s12">
  <input class="btn waves-effect waves-light" id="submit" type="submit" name="action" style="width:33%; margin-left:20%; margin-bottom:4%">
 </div>
 @*</div>*@
</form>
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Session["userID"] = "IT14111884";
    string sessionValue = Session["userID"].ToString();
    if (Session["userID"].ToString() == null) return View("Login");

    person1 = repo.GetPeronById(sessionValue);
    var model = person1;
    //DateTime da = (DateTime)person1.DOB;
    //DateTime date2 = ;
    //DateTime.ToString("dd MMM yyyy")
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult saveChanges(person person1)
{
    person _person = new person();
    _person.SID = person1.SID;
    _person.FirstName = person1.FirstName;
    _person.LastName = person1.LastName;
    _person.Address = person1.Address;
    _person.Phone = person1.Phone;
    _person.DOB = person1.DOB;
    _person.password = person1.password;
    _person.email = person1.email;
    //Session["_person"] = _person;

    string sessionValue = Session["userID"].ToString();
    bool status;
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    status = repo.updatePerson(sessionValue,_person);

    return Json(status, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadPhoto(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var user = Session["userID"].ToString();
        var fileExt = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);


        if (fileExt.ToLower().EndsWith(".png") || fileExt.ToLower().EndsWith(".jpg"))
        {
            var fileName = user + ".png";
            var filePath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/profile/") + fileName;
            var directory = new DirectoryInfo(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/profile/"));

            if (directory.Exists == false)
            {
                directory.Create();
            }
            ViewBag.FilePath = filePath.ToString();
            file.SaveAs(filePath);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { Message = ManageMessageId.PhotoUploadSuccess });

        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { Message = ManageMessageId.FileExtensionError });

        }

    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { Message = ManageMessageId.Error });

}


public enum ManageMessageId
{
    Error,
    PhotoUploadSuccess,
    FileExtensionError
}
```

Reporsitory class

```
public bool updatePerson(string ID,person _objPerson)
    {
        //_dbContext.people.Add(_objPerson);
        person temp = null;
        try
        {
            temp = (from p in _dbContext.people
                    where p.SID == ID
                    select p).SingleOrDefault();
            temp.FirstName = _objPerson.FirstName;
            temp.LastName = _objPerson.LastName;
            temp.Address = _objPerson.Address;
            temp.Phone = _objPerson.Phone;
            temp.DOB = _objPerson.DOB;
            temp.password = _objPerson.password;
            temp.email = _objPerson.email;
            //_dbContext.SaveChanges();
            //Guid id = _objPerson.Person_ID;
            if (_dbContext.SaveChanges() > 0)
            {
                return true;
            }



        }
        catch (DbUpdateException e)
        {
            string msg = (e.InnerException.Message);
            //Console.ReadLine();

        }
        return false;

    }
```

Comment: Please point out where the error occurs, also try debugging via breakpoint and check the values after your post.

Comment: Somewhere in your C# code you have a NULL, where it cannot handle an NULL. Find the place where it occurs. Maybe you can find the place of the error by the stacktrace or by debugging?

Comment: @Colinm Please check the question. I have updated the question. I tried debugging but it didn't help.

Comment: @Arendax, Please check the question. I have updated the question. I tried to find where problem is but I couldn't

Comment: @Mike you only edited the code and said that you could not find the problem but it needs to occur in the code you uploaded here.

Comment: What I meant in the previous comment is to point out the exact line of code where the error occurs

Comment: @ColinM he can't find where the problem occurs

Comment: Arendax you are right even I'm confused. I will try again Colinm

Comment: Place a breakpoint in the view and step through the code

Comment: I think you could not find the problem because of that the problem is in you json/javascript code, there does the debugger not work.

Comment: May be I did some quick changes in javascript part

Comment: @Mike okay, it is in the javascript part.

Comment: @Arendax if the problem in javascript why doesn't the page load?

Comment: It gives an error? Right? You said: "I get this exception.....".

Comment: In your `POST` from Ajax, you pass a JSON property `Password`, whereas it seems that your `person` model class accepts `password`, notice the case difference. **But**, the error here is relating to the View, not the POST or any C# code. Place a Breakpoint on any of the C# code in the View and you'll be able to step through via F10 when Debugging

Comment: @Colinm, I don't think that is the problem. Because it was there even before the error

Comment: Look at the rest of my message, I'll wait for a response on that

Comment: @Colinm, I tried to debug, I think the problem is with Model.SID. I tried to assign it to a var and there same exception appeared. (In the place where var variable is)

Comment: Did you simply launch in Debug, or did you place a breakpoint on `Model.SID` and check the value of that? You can also place a breakpoint on `return View(model);` in the Controller and check the values of `model` to make sure that or the values are not null.

Comment: @Colinm, I tried both. I think the problem is there. Because SID doesn't show any value. Also intellisense doesnt work for Model property.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130515/discussion-between-colinm-and-mike).